# How to log data from RDD without doing transformations or output operations in Spark after exception is caught in driver

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to log all the data that failed in a dStream but I am getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adding new inputs, transformations, and output operations after stopping a context is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.validateAtInit(DStream.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.<init>(DStream.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.<init>(MappedDStream.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.map(DStream.scala:527)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$class.map(JavaDStreamLike.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.AbstractJavaDStreamLike.map(JavaDStreamLike.scala:43)
```

Comment: some code samples of what you're exactly doing would be very helpful

Comment: I will post sample code of what I am trying to do.